# If $x$ and $y$ are irrational, then $x^y$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

I thought it was true, however my textbook claims it to be false. I need a counter example but I can't really think of one.

Comment: $x = e$ and $y = \ln 2$.  Then $x^y = 2$.

Comment: Or $x = 5^{\sqrt 2}$ and $y = \sqrt 2$ or ....

Answer (score 1):

You can easily construct a counterexample.

Let $x=\sqrt{3}$ and $y=\sqrt{2}$ so both $x,y$ are irrational.

Now either $x^y$ is rational in which case we have a counterexample. Or it is irrational and when you raise it to the power of $y$ which is irrational you definitely get something rational

$$
(x^y)^y=3.
$$

where both base and exponent were irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using Euler's Identity:

$$ e^{i\pi} = -1 $$

where $$ x = e$$

and $$ y = {i\pi} $$